super inconsistent animation in css and javascript
I want to make a scrolling button, where the text part scrolls out when you hover on it and scroll back when you stop hovering, but the animation is really inconsistent.
This code works on the first cycle, but just breaks apart during the subsequent cycles, no_length somehow gets applied when I am still hovering over the button, and when I hover off the classList is somehow both no_length and full_length, sometimes the disappear animation just does not get finished and the bar instantly disappear, sometimes there is lag when I hover on the button, I have tried removing every class on hover and then applying them later, I have tried to add a is_transitioning state to stop it from continuously being executed, but none of those seem to work.


var is_transitioning = false;

$(".btn").hover(appear, dissappear);


function appear() {
  if (!is_transitioning) {
    is_transitioning = true;
    $(".button").removeClass("no_length");
    $(".button").removeClass("full_length");
    $(".button").removeClass("del_btn");
    $(".button").addClass("move_btn");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".button").addClass("full_length");
      $(".button").removeClass("move_btn");

    }, 2000);
  }
}

function dissappear() {
  $(".button").removeClass("full_length");
  $(".button").addClass("del_btn");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".button").addClass("no_length");
    $(".button").removeClass("del_btn");
    is_transitioning = false; // Reset transition state after the transition
  }, 2000); // Time for disappear transition
}
.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  .button {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
  }
  .button_circle {
    border-color: #3f51b5;
  }
}

.button {
  background-color: #4f7b8a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 0;
  color: #E5E4E2;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  z-index: 0;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.full_length {
  width: 100px!important;
}

.no_length {
  width: 0px!important;
}

.button_circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #4f7b8a;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.move_btn {
  animation: appear 2s 0s 1 ease;
}

.del_btn {
  animation: dissapear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes dissapear {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <span class="button_circle"></span>
  <button class="button" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
</div>




You can simplify it by using a css transition instead of animation.  Here is an example based on your code.


.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width:250px;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  .button {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
  }
  .button_circle {
    border-color: #3f51b5;
  }
}

.button {
  background-color: #4f7b8a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 0;
  color: #E5E4E2;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  z-index: 0;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* added properties */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
}

.button_circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #4f7b8a;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* added rules */
.button {
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in;
  width: 0;
}
.btn:hover .button {
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  width: 200px;
}
<div class="btn">
  <span class="button_circle"></span>
  <button class="button" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
</div>



